# Unauthorized when trying to connect to an API with Python

Tags: python, api, get

I am trying to connect to an external API thought Python and need some help.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import requests

url = 'https://myurlwithanAPI'
         }
headers = {'Authorization':'XXXXXX'}
response = requests.get(url, params = headers, verify=False)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.content)
else:
    print('Error: Code',response.status_code)
    print(response.content)
    print(response.url)
```

When I run it, I always get a `response_code = 401` with a `response.content = 'Unauthorized'`

I though I was something regarding the `Authorization key`, however, when I try to connect by using the web application [https://apitester.com/] with the same URL and the same header (`Authorization`) it works fine. What am I missing?

Thank you very much

Comment: try `requests.get(url, headers=headers)`. Also you have a hanging right-bracket

Comment: Thank you very much! It was that simple, now it seems to work fine.